# Black and blank areas within applications or pop-ups windows!

Tags: unity

I'm using 14.04 and recently I'm facing an annoying graphical issues with some application. After launching some apps I find some black/transparent/blank areas and can't see what's behind it unless I hover over all these black areas!

- Here is a popup window when I tried to upload files:

  [image: screenshot 1]
- Here is a Blank window:

  [image: screenshot 2]

  I'm not allowed to add more screenshots so I hope those two are enough to get an insight about the problem.

Graphics card details:

- Intel HD 520 and AMD R5 M335 (HD 8600M as shown in additional driver)

Here is the `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'`output

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 06b2
        Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
```

Note: Kernel version is already the newest v ersion.

How can I get rid off this annoying problem?

Side note: I couldn't install the AMD propriety driver

Comment: It would be useful if you could [edit] your question and add some detail about your graphics card and used driver, for example the output of the terminal command `lspci -k | grep -iEA3 '3D|VGA'`. Thanks.

Comment: I've added more details and the command's output as well

Comment: You are using a pretty new processor/integrated graphics chip (Intel Skylake / 6th generation) with the 3 years old 14.04 Ubuntu release. Its kernel version simply does not support the new Skylake chips well yet. The best way would probably be to upgrade your Ubuntu release to 16.04 (next LTS version) or 17.04 (latest normal version), which ship with a newer kernel that supports Skylake graphics.

Comment: Maybe you can also try just updating the kernel version by installing the package `linux-generic-lts-xenial` first, so that you don't have to do a full release upgrade if it works.

Comment: It's already the newest version. But 14.04 ubuntu was working good with this chip, I don't know what happened to cause this problem. Also I used 16.04 but for some reasons related to installing the AMD propriety driver I downgraded to 14.04.

Comment: Why would you need an AMD driver? Don't you have only the integrated Intel graphics chip? Also, please show the output of `uname -r`, which describes your kernel version.

Comment: No. I mentioned that I have both intel and AMD in the question description.  But AMD driver not installed yet. 

kernel version: 4.4.0-75-generic

Comment: Oh, right. I'm surprised that it doesn't show up in lspci then though. Kernel 4.4 should have at least some support for Skylake though.